# Do the end caps on this fuse get transferred to the new fuse when/if it blows?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

This is one of the time delay fuses in the box outside by my a/c condensor unit:
[image]

New ones don't come with the copper end caps as far as I can tell:
[image]

I'm guessing they just get pried off the bad fuse and pressed onto the new fuse??

Comment: Look like they do, but top one does not look to be in original condition.  Might need to replace it, so you have a tight connection.

Comment: Yes, it looks bad but that split appears to be OEM

Comment: System is brand new.....installed about a month ago. I'm thinking the split is there so it can be pulled off and placed on another fuse. If it wasn't split it would be next to impossible to get it on and off.

Comment: Please have mercy and don't embed images with so high resolution. I'm on 160 Mbit connection and it took server like 10 seconds to serve me the first image in your post.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, it appears these adapters are common.

https://www.supplyhouse.com/DiversiTech-626-38632-Fuse-Adapter-60-to-30-Reducer-for-Class-H-250V

[image]

Comment: I Googled for a bit trying to find those.....guess my search wording was off.

Comment: I used:  ecnr fuse end caps

Comment: They are called "fuse reducers" -- they aren't meant to be *permanent* per se, but sometimes, you don't have much of a choice

Comment: Are you saying that sometimes the reducers will "fuse" to the end of the time delay fuse during an over current event?

Comment: I read that as you may not be able to find the right size right away, and you're not going to go back to it later down the road to try and find the right size again.

Answer (score 10):

Those adapters are used to adapt the smaller fuses to a 60 amp style fuse socket and yes they are removable and transferred.